# What is preventing me from accessing a 3rd-level nested ESXi host?

Tags: esxi

I have an ESXi 6.5 host with an IP address of 172.16.10.11. Within that ESXi host, I have a virtual machine running an ESXi 6.5 host with an IP address of 172.16.20.11. And finally within the nested ESXi host, I have another virtual machine with an ESXi host with an IP address of 172.16.30.11.

So, to clarify I have a nested ESXi host, inside a nested ESXi host, inside an ESXi host. My problem is that I cannot access the deepest ESXi host from my network. When I installed it it could not find the DHCP server. I assigned a static IP address to it, but I cannot connect to that IP address from my network whether it is trying to ping it or connect to the web interface.

I can connect to the 1st and 2nd level hosts just fine. I can also ping the 3rd level host from the 2nd level host just fine using DCUI.  As it is the weekend I do not have access to the physical machine to try pinging from the 1st level host.

Since I am able to access the 1st level and 2nd level hosts from my network, and since the 2nd level host can access the 3rd level host, what is preventing me from accessing the 3rd level host from my network?

PS. I realize that technically nested ESXi hosts are not officially supported by VMware.

Comment: My guess is knowing vmware products pretty well you have simply ran into the limits of esxi

Comment: @Ramhound Can you be a bit more specific as to what limits you are referring to?

Comment: What you describe requires passing the hardware virtualization capability of your CPU to software.  The only product I know that can do that twice actually is Hyper-V

Comment: Under the VM settings for CPU, I have made sure to check off "Hardware virtualization - Expose hardware assisted virtualization to the guest OS". I have done that for each VM. Is that what you are referring to?

Comment: Yes, which leads me to my previous comment, only Hypervisor Type 1 know which can do nested virtualization twice is Hyper-V

Comment: @Ramhound Thank you for your help. I have found a work around that will do for now.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the problem by setting the virtual switch to promiscuous mode. While this may not work for everyone's situation and could be a security risk as it will send traffic through to every port similar to a hub, it is an acceptable work around for me.

In case it helps anyone else, the process I followed was this:

- In the main ESXi host web interface, selected Networking from the left column
- Select the Virtual Switches tab
- Click vSwitch0 (assuming this is your switch)
- Click "Edit Settings"
- Select "Security"
- Set "Promiscuous Mode" to accept. All the other settings on that page should have already been set to accept by default.